# Adding Radio Button on Suitelet SS2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am adding the radio button on Suitlet page but it is throwing an error while loading the page. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
                        var custType1 = form.addField({
                            id: 'custpage_customertype',
                            name: 'retail_customer',
                            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
                            label: 'Retail Customer',
                            container: 'companygroup'
                         });
                         var custType2 = form.addField({
                             id: 'custpage_customertype',
                             name: 'corporate_customer',
                             type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
                             label: 'Corporate Customer',
                             container: 'companygroup'
                         });
                         var custType3 = form.addField({
                             id: 'custpage_customertype',
                             name: 'external_customer',
                             type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
                             label: 'External Customer',
                             container: 'companygroup'
                         });
```

While running the code, I am getting error on this line saying SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT. Following is the error code -

*{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"nlobjField: Missing a required argument: radiobuttons: sSource","stack":["addField(N/serverWidget)","(/SuiteScripts/sdr_sw_suitelet_test.js:123)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","details":"nlobjField: Missing a required argument: radiobuttons: sSource","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["addField(N/serverWidget)","(/SuiteScripts/sdr_sw_suitelet_test.js:123)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}*

Answer (score 2):

You need a source property which will be like the id of the radio button.  This will be the value used by the script to know which radio button was selected.  Something like

```
var custType1 = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_customertype',
    name: 'retail_customer',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
    label: 'Retail Customer',
    source:'retail',
    container: 'companygroup'
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I was considering name property as id of the radio button.